# Vue datagrid approach advice

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, underscore.js, axios

This snippet works as is. But my approach to achieve this functionality is slightly different like approach used in demos on vuejs.org. What I really need to know is which method is best to achieve filtered list of users from original data. Whether my filter() method is good idea, or better is computed, or watched.

**If snipet doesnt work**: Mockaroo have (sometimes) ssl certificate problem. So you must open data url in browsers new tab first ( https://api.mockaroo.com/api/b5f38710?count=20&key=cdbbbcd0 ), confirm security exception, delete downloaded json a then run this code snippet again.

```js
var dataurl ='https://api.mockaroo.com/api/b5f38710?count=20&key=cdbbbcd0'

new Vue({
  el: '#datagrid',
  data: {
    columns: {
      id: 'ID',
      nick: 'Nick name',
      first: 'First name',
      last: 'Last name'
    },
    users: [],
    query: '',
    prevKey: 'id',
    orderDesc: false
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUsers () {
      return _.filter(this.users, user =>
        _.find(user, prop =>
          new RegExp(this.query, 'i').test(prop)
        )
      )
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async loadUsers () {
      var result = await axios.get(dataurl)
      this.users = result.data
      this.query = ''
      this.prevKey = 'id'
      this.orderDesc = false
    },
    clearQuery () {
      this.query = ''
    },
    sortUsers (e) {
      var key = e.target.dataset.key
      if (this.prevKey === key) {
        this.users.reverse()
        this.orderDesc = !this.orderDesc
      } else {
       this.users = _.sortBy(this.users, key)
        this.orderDesc = false
       this.prevKey = key
      }
    },
    updateQuery: _.debounce(function (e) {
      this.query = e.target.value
    }, 300)
  }
})
```

```css
#datagrid {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #3F51B5;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #263238;
}
.thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}
.tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
.thead .td {
  padding: 5px 14px;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tbody .td {
  padding: 4px;
  color: #263238;
  text-align: center;
}
.tr .td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}
.tbody .tr:hover .td {
  background-color: #C5CAE9;
}
.tbody .tr:hover .td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 2px solid #C5CAE9;
}
.tools {
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tools:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.source {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.search {
  float: right;
}
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  transition: all .6s;
}
.asc {
  border-bottom: 6px solid white;
}
.desc {
  border-top: 6px solid white;
}
.users-move {
  transition: transform .6s;
}
.users-enter-active, .users-leave-active {
  transition: all .6s;
}
.users-enter, .users-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/underscore@1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.16.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="datagrid">
  <div class="tools">
    <button class="source" @click="loadUsers">
      Load some fake data from mockaroo.com
    </button>   
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" @input="updateQuery" :value="query">
      <button class="clear" @click="clearQuery">clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="thead" @click="sortUsers">
      <div class="tr">
        <span v-for="(col, key) in columns" class="td" :data-key=key>
          {{ col }}
          <span
            v-if="prevKey === key"
            :class="['arrow', orderDesc ? 'desc' : 'asc']">
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <transition-group name="users" tag="div" class="tbody">
      <div class="tr" v-for="row in filteredUsers" :key="row.id">
        <span class="td" v-for="column in row">{{ column }}</span>
      </div>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Computed is the way to go, since it will react to any change you make in users/query

Comment: @fatman My filter() method also responds to any user / query changes. So why is computed better?

Comment: See this from Vue creator: https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/830/method-vs-computed-vs-filter/2

Comment: @fatman Done... But again, as in point 4. of answer, it seems to be ok to use method for filtering.

Comment: yes, but computed has a nicer syntax, so i'd prefer to use them when i can